# How to find the relationship between two cameras?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, temporal

First, suppose there are two cameras in fixed position, and there is a certain overlap area. Next, some moving objects may pass through two fields of view. So, if objects pass the overlap area, I think I can use the trajectory(with timestam in self-camera) of this movement to explore the relationship between the two fields of view.   (two camera has different timestamp).

So, now if I know the trajectory in two cameras, but don't know the relation in differernt cameras. I want to get relative position/orientation about the two camera.

What algorithm can solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: @OleV.V. I assume that was a typo, considering the word "two" was used in the title.

Comment: @OleV.V. I assume that the OP is using a two-camera setup or a moving single camera.

Comment: yeah, two-camera. sorry about my poor English.

Comment: may this photo helps to understand this problem

Comment: its absolutely unclear what is known and what you want to compute/achieve. We can only guess that by horizon you mean camera but do you know the relative position/orientation between cameras or that is what you want to obtain? do you know FOV of the cameras? Do you have the observed trajectories with timestamps or you got just the position info? Are the cameras in fixed relative position to eachother? Do you know which trajectories from one view correlate to the other view? The input trajectories are in vector form (2D cartesian)?

Comment: I would try something like this: 1. use single trajectory 2. for each of its pixel compute time. 3. resample trajectory from view1 and view2 so you get consequent points at the same times 4. now fit/compute the camera FOW using the resampled points. the x,y position in view will give you direction vector of ray from camera focal point to the object as relative camera orientation and position are unknonws you need to construct a system of equations (using more points) and either solve or fit it until both views match. However this is far from solid answer/aproach and untested hence only comment

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the 2. point ， Can you speak in more detail?